# Django: speech to text application

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, jython

first do you know what language google used to create the speech to text search?

then can you create a speech to text django or google apps engine using python? i'm not a vb.net programmer and yes i know that such applications are usually created in java, couldn't they be created in jython? i have a django app i would like to introduce this feature to it.

i can use [ispeech](http://www.ispeech.org) (not free!) or similar services, but before working with APIs (i don't like working with APIs to be honest unless it is facebook or google API), i'm looking to see if there's a python or jython library for that (i prefer python)

i found so far [pyspeech](http://code.google.com/p/pyspeech/) it works on windows and my vps is linux so won't do me any good

Comment: speech to text...not text to speech...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlikely.

As you cannot install binaries in the Google App Engine environment, you would need build an entire speech recognition engine from scratch. This would be ..non-trival.

If you are not limited to Google App Engine however, there are Python bindings to existing packages, such as [Sphinx](http://sphinx.subwiki.com/sphinx/index.php/Sphinx3_python_quickstart)

Comment: isn't sphinx a search engine?

Comment: @Eli: The "Sphinx" name is shared by multiple open-source projects. Sphinx happens to be the name of both a speech recognition library and a search engine.

Comment: App engine 2.7 will support including binary code. 
[Here][1] you can find some more information about chrome accessibility in particular. I will attend the Google Developer's Day in Berlin and I have noticed that there is a talk about a build in screen reader (text to speech) for chrome. I think its a matter of time..


  [1]: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility

Comment: I am sorry I was writing about text to speech :)

Comment: @Chris-Top although i'm asking about speech to text, thank you for telling me about text to speech lol, coz i'm looking to create an interactive app where you talk and the computer talk, I haven't mention text to speech in my question just because i found many libraries for that :)